# Running django with mod_python on a shared apache server

Tags: django, apache, mod-python

I'm in a university and I'm provided with a public_html folder where I can put my CGI scripts. For eg. when I put PHP scripts and visit them from my browser, it works correctly and the PHP is properly interpreted.

I wish to run Django apps in this environment and I know that the university runs an apache server and had mod_php and mod_python installed, although I think I'm not allowed to modify the httpd.conf etc.

All the tutorials that I've read about Django on mod_python ask me to modify the httpd.conf, is there any way I can get my Django site running by making non-sudo changes only?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your directives in a .htaccess file in your directory.  Dependent on the server config, it might work.